# Python 3: Sort Dict of DF's by Column Value from Last Row

Tags: python, dictionary

Dict of df's:

```
years = [2017, 2018, 2019]
dfcols = ['Count', 'Amount']
dataframedict = {'CatA': pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7]], columns=dfcols, index=years), 
                'CatB': pd.DataFrame(data=[[4, 8], [5, 9], [6, 19]], columns=dfcols, index=years), 
                'CatC': pd.DataFrame(data=[[7,11], [8,12], [9,13]], columns=dfcols, index=years)}
```

Need a list of dict keys sorted descending by 'Amount' in 2019, so ['CatB', 'CatC', 'CatA']

Tried, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853024/sort-dictionary-of-dictionaries-by-value-python-3-level-dict) variations of:

```
for k in sorted(dataframedict, key=lambda df: df.Amount[-1], reverse=True):
    print(k)
```

Getting error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Amount'`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your dict to a sort list of tuples:

```
for k, v in sorted(dataframedict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].Amount.iloc[-1], reverse=True):
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
CatB
CatC
CatA
```

Note that I am passing `.items()` to the `sorted`. Each one is a tuple of length 2 (`x[0]` is the key and `x[1]` is the value/df).

Now, regarding your error: When you pass a dict in sorted, the keys of the dict are considered:

```
>>> a = {1: "ad", 0: "ads"}
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x)
[0, 1]
```

Thus you are passing strings in the `lambda`

Comment: @James: You are not iterating a list of tuples so my `k` was a tuple. I have now unpacked it to key and value - EDIT: I see what you are saying - just copied the original code - not tested but seems that `iloc` solves the issue right?

Comment: This still gives a key error, **not** from the dictionary, but from the trying to grab the `[-1]` index from the `Amount` column of the data frame.  That index does not exist, so a `KeyError` arises.  Does the for-loop work for you?

Comment: @James, fixed the `iloc` - Just took a while to get a terminal here :). I also think is good to provide an explanation on why the original error occurred (and why the df key error happens in the Amount) to make the answer complete

Comment: Thanks to both this user and @James, I'm accepting this answer for the more detailed explanation and upvoting the other reply

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a list, you can use a list comprehension and the `.items` method of the dictionary to retrieve the key and dataframe

```
[
    k for k, df 
    in sorted(dataframedict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].Amount.iloc[-1], reverse=True)
]
# returns:
['CatB', 'CatC', 'CatA']
```